# How to set 3 digits after comma

Tags: c++

Well, basically I was using setprecision(3), but that is rounding up the last number, for example if we do like this -

```
double x = 5;
x = (double) x / 3;
cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << x << endl;
```

It will show 1.667

But, if we do it with calculator, it will show - 1.666666666...67

So basically, what I mean is, is there any chance to output in file, just the first 3 digits after the comma, and not to round it up?

Comment: You'll notice that the calculator is rounding up as well, it just shows more digits. Why do you not want to round?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << double(int(x*1000))/1000 << endl;
```

we use `int()` to truncate the tailing digits.

Comment: and it is not works if you have result 11.6666666 for example.

Comment: To make it work for either negative or positives, you can tweak it like so: `x + ((x<0)? +0.005 : -0.005)`.

Comment: that does not work either for results with different valuable digits. Just try 100.666666666 .

Answer (score 4):

1.666666666...67 rounded to three decimal places is 1.667

If you just want to truncate the output then send it to a string with strstream, search the string for the position of "." and truncate the string 3 places beyond that

Or if you simply want to always round down, multiply the result by 1000, use floor() to round down and then divide by 1000.0 again.

Comment: Hello, well basically I could use the string thing, let me check how it goes on.

Answer (score 0):

A cast to long truncates the fraction part :

```
int main()
{
  double x;
  x=  -100.666666666666666;
  x = static_cast<double> ( static_cast<long>(x * 1000) )/1000;
  cout << x << endl;
}
```

We could use `floor(double)` from `cmath`, which is more preferable, but it's rounds negatives to negative side either.

Comment: we can do that `cout << static_cast<double> ( static_cast<long>(x * 1000) )/1000; << endl;` or even that `cout << format(x, 3);` I made step by step for better clarity, not for copy and paste.